# where can I register Android app on google for xoauth for consumer key and consumer secret

Tags: android, oauth, gmail

I'm developing a Androd app that interacts with Gmail through XOauth. And i want to register my app on google otherwise during the OAuth process, Google will show a warning and treat my app as "unable to verify this claim....We recommend you deny access unless you trust the application". I'm afraid this warning would scare of some users. So i wonder where can I register my Android app on google for xoauth for consumer key and consumer secret? I searched the web for hours and only find this https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto. But my app is not web app and don't have a domain. Where can i found the Android app version?

Answer (score 1):

https://code.google.com/apis/console

Select API Access from the left and follow the instructions there.

Comment: More specifically, "Create an OAuth 2.0 Client ID", enter information, "Installed Application", "Android"

Comment: Seems your link is for registering API key for OAuth 2.0. There is no consumer key and consumer secret. But what i need is registering for consumer key and secret for XOAuth, or OAuth1.0.